# JBoss 6.1 App server startup problems:Module not found exception

Tags: jboss6.x

My JBoss Application server is throwing a Module not found exception when starting it.I unzipped Jboss and started it. Could you please tell if i have to make any configuration setting to make it start.

```
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.standalone:main
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:224)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:341)
```

Press any key to continue . . .

Thanks,
-Vijay

Comment: You should add more tags to your question to increase its visibility.

Comment: @user2970979, do you find any reasons?

Comment: Did you get this error, *before* trying to deploy anything on it?

Answer (score 2):

A possible reason is your jboss runtime is corrupt. Reason for

```
**org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.standalone:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:224)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:341)**
```

is that `jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\server\main` package is missing inside your jboss directory. This package contains **jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar** and **module.xml** which are essential to run jboss server.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to finally solve it with some help from someone from the Jboss community.

You can see the answer here: https://community.jboss.org/message/737218#737218

Basically I turned on TRACE logging on the modules and saw that I'm actually missing javax.jms.Destination, so I just added dependency to that module.

Comment: where did you add the dependency?